# limit the dialog inteval in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences, progressdialog

I am making a call to server from my android app. I have done this using **AsyncTask** Thread.
Now I have started Progress Dialog in **onPreExecute()** Method as follows:

```
protected void onPreExecute(){ 
dialog = new ProgressDialog(appcontext);
dialog.setMessage("Sending Position...");
dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.show();
}
```

Now, in **doInBackground()** method I have been doing my sending data tasks.And after I get the response I am going to **onPostExecute()**  method where I have used **dialog.dismiss()** to stop **ProgressDialog**.

**my doInBackGround() code**

```
protected String doInBackground(Position... position){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String temp=null;
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8084/WebApplication5/getData");
String json = "";
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
try { 
     jsonObject.accumulate("time",position[0].getTime()); 
     json = jsonObject.toString();
     StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
     httpPost.setEntity(se);
     httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
     httpPost.setHeader("Content", "application/json");
     org.apache.http.HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

  **// CODE ACTUALLY BLOCKS HERE UNTIL I GET A RESPONSE.(WHAT I THINKS). THOUGH WORKS 99%** 

     inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
     if(inputStream!=null)
          temp="sent"; 
 }
 catch (JSONException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 catch (IllegalStateException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     } 
 catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
    return temp;
}
```

ALL IS FINE but sometimes I do not get a response (let it be any server error), In that case the dialog is unable to dismissed and is running undefinitely. I want to limit the duration of **doInBackGround()** method for few seconds. So that even in case of no response it will move to **onPostExecute()** and my infinte going dialog should stop.

Secondly, In case I get a response I want to save it to my SharedPreferences, so my question is what is the best way to do that, i.e.

1) I should do it in **onPause()** method.

2) or, in **onStop()** method,

3) or in **onPostExecut()e** method

or there is no point in that, I can do it anywhere.

And my last question is what is the what is the lifetime of data that is stored in Shared Preferences.

Comment: Post onPostExecute code too. --- Your doBackground will finish you should add something which reports a fail. Or add more info about doBackground

Comment: in postExecute I am just using dialog.dismiss() and starting other activity.

Comment: Your doBackground will run forever if something went wrong? Add doBackground code, it's not normal.

Comment: i have edited the question. please see it again..

Comment: You could add a timeout: https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/params/HttpConnectionParams.html#setSoTimeout(int)

Comment: whose method is this?? i mean by which object i should call out this method.

Comment: and plss answer rest two questions,, i know they are easy but still..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save it where you want, you could save it after you get it or in `onPause` (which is called when your activity is paused)

Save it in `onPause` if the user is going to modify it and you need to save it.

Or, if you just need it and you will not change it anymore save it in `onPostExecute`, or everytime you change it.

`SharedPreference` don't have a "lifetime" it will exists until the application is in the device, or until the user don't clear data app.

For your `doBackground` you could add a timeout to your request.

Change your code block:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

to

```
BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS); // example: 2000 for 2 seconds
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
```

Comment: please give me the object name by which I should call setSoTimeOut(). and thanks.. btw.. :)